# TextBox with TwoWay DataBinding (double) does not allow decimal separator

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, double

I have the following textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="VoorzieningBerging"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextChanged="SimulatieWijziging"
         Margin="0,0,45,0" Width="60" Height="25">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="VoorzieningParameters[0].Double"
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                 FallbackValue="0" Mode="OneWayToSource">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <src:DoubleValidation/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And in the viewModel:

```
VoorzieningParameters = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();
VoorzieningParameters.Add(new Parameter() { Naam = "berging" });
```

Where Parameter is a Class with a description (Naam) and a double for value.

```
public class Parameter
{
    public Parameter()
    {

    }

    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public double? Double { get; set; }
}
```

This is working fine, I enter data in the textbox and when I hit the save button I loop through all the "Parameters" in my ObservableCollection and write them to XML. However now I want to make a load button but instead of writing the values into the Textboxes I'd like to just set the Parameters in the viewmodel and use a TwoWay binding instead. However when I change the binding mode to TwoWay the Textbox no longer accepts a decimal separator (, or .). When I try to input 7.0 it just sais 70.

Ive tried using string format on the Textbox, it then allows a seperator but when I try to input something like 7.0 it becomes 7.0.0

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: TextBox.Text is by default String, try to use Converter to cast it do Double

Comment: Could you give me an example? I have tried a few converters without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set binding to double it automatically calls .ToString() so there is no need to use Converter to display its value in TextBox.Text. Unfortunately, it does not allow to put '.' or ',' as you described. I have couple solutions

1. Like you said you can use StringFormat as follows, StringFormat={}{0:0.0}}, but then you cannot write 7.0 but only write 7 or change number after dot.
2. Second approach is to change type of your property from Double to string. Then inputting ',' is allowed but you will have to cast it to double whenever you wish to use it.
3. I ran into already available solution, take a look [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/double-text-box)

Comment: Yeah yesterday I solved it by changing my property's to strings, for this application it's not a big deal because I feed the property's to XML so I have to convert them to string anyway but for future use I was hoping there would be a better solution for this. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

For your binding, try adding a Delay. I use 300, you can use any number. This seems to do the trick for my applications.

For example:

```
    <Binding Path="VoorzieningParameters[0].Double"
                     ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                     Delay=300
                     FallbackValue="0" Mode="OneWayToSource">
```